# Should I add past full time experience for internship

Tags: software-industry, internship

I am an international student in Canada. Currently, I am pursuing Master's in Computer Science from a well reputed University and I am incline to apply for summer internships. Before coming to Canada, I have worked professionally four years in India as a software developer. My concern is, should I mention this in my resume for internship? Will it be overkill for internship? I will be applying to similar jobs as my professional experience?

I have asked it at academia stack exchange but I have suggested to ask here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any downside to including it, if you were applying to an internship but weren't studying then you would run the risk of looking overqualified but your Masters program gives you a perfectly reasonable explanation as to why you are applying to internships rather than full employment in spite of your prior professional experience.

Answer (score 1):

As a masters student this can only be a good thing for you. It means you have more to offer than the average or next potential intern. Just don't sell yourself short in your choosing, you bring a great deal of value to the table.

Best of luck

T